# PHP Login just refreshes

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, page-refresh

Trying to make a login page. I get no errors or any of the echos that I should it just refreshes the page again when I click the Login button.

**Connection**

```
<?php

class Connection{    

   public function dbConnect(){

      $db_host = "";
      $db_username = "";
      $db_password = "";
      $db_name = "";

      try{
         $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name , $db_username , $db_password);
         $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
         //This is just to test if connection was succesfull.      
         echo "Success!";
      }
      catch(PDOException $e){
         echo "Server Error: ".$e->getMessage()."". "Unable to connect to server.";
      }
      return $db;
   }
}
?>
```

**Users**

```
<?php 

include_once("connection.php");

class Users{

       private $db; 

   public function __construct(){

      $this->db = new Connection();
      $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();   
   }

   public function Login($username, $password){

      if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

          $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ? AND password= ?");
          $stmt->bindParam(1,$username);
          $stmt->bindParam(2,$password);
          $stmt->execute();

          if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
             echo "Successfully logged in!";
          }else{
             echo "Incorrect username or password please try again.";
          }         

      }else{
          echo"Must type a username and password to login.";
      }
   }
}
?>
```

This is where the actual form for the login page is. I have a short php code on top of the whole html.

```
<?php

include_once("login.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 

   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
   $user = new User();
   $user->Login($username, $password);
}
?>
```

And here is the actual form part:

```
<form method ="post" action="index.php">
<input class="classname2" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"><br><br>
<input class="classname2" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"><br><br>
<input class="classname" type="submit" value="Login" ><br><br>
<input class="classname" type="submit" value="SignUp" formaction="signup.php">
</form>
```

Okay so now its working somewhat after adding the name to the login button. Now the query or something is going wrong. I changed what would happen if the rowCount() == 1 because the header("Location:...") is giving me a : Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/49/11554349/html/gb/dev/connection.php:15) in /home/content/49/11554349/html/gb/dev/login.php on line 25. And I also changed it to echo successfully logged in because it was still running that part of the code even though I put a wrong password for that username.

Comment: You don't have a form field `name='submit'` so `$_POST['submit']` will never be set. Add a `name='submit'` attribute to the login button.

Comment: that definitely fixed part of the problem, now the query is messed up or something it is still running the code if the password is wrong and the header is popping an alert

Comment: This code implies that you are storing passwords in plain text (unsalted, unhashed) which is _really bad_. If you did in fact hash them before storing, you are not correspondingly hashing the input password to test against.

Answer (score 1):

You should give your submit input a name. E.g.: `name="submit"`

```
<input class="classname" name="submit" type="submit" value="SignUp" formaction="signup.php">
```

When you use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` you check by name in the `_POST` array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use, Added `name="submit"` attribute in `<input/>` tag

```
<input class="classname" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" ><br><br>
```

instead of

```
<input class="classname" type="submit" value="Login" ><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have any data called "submit" to reference. I usually check the size of the $_POST array (because isset doesn't work since it's usually an empty array).

```
if (sizeof($_POST) != 0) {
    // ....
}
```

It looks like right now none of your login code is being processed since there is no $_POST['submit'].